# Is there a way to detect the undeployment of an EJB?

Tags: weblogic, ejb

I need to do some clean up (release open ports,etc.) before my EJB Session Bean is being undeployed, is there a way to detect this?

The EJB is running on Weblogic 10.0.

Comment: ejb 2 or 3? How and when are the resources being initially allocated?

Comment: I believe it's ejb3 as it's Weblogic 10

Comment: sure it's EJB 3.0. I am creating SSHTunnels, thus allocating network ports in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue in a Weblogic-specific way by implementing an `ApplicationLifecycleListener`. Details can be seen [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/programming/lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not make use of the session bean lifecycle by using `@PreDestroy` as illustrated [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/StatefulSessionBeanLifecyclePreDestroy.htm) ?

Comment: it sounded great to me bu somehow it didnt work on Weblogic 10.

Answer (score -1):

Listen to the lifcecycle events using the [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface.

Implement the interface in a class, and register it in web.xml:

```
 <listener>
<listener-class>
    my-class-with-servlet-contextlistener-interface
</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: Aren't we looking at session beans, not servlets ?

Comment: Assuming the whole EAR is being undeployed your servlets go with them.